# Simplificar validaciones con ciclo for en python

Tags: python, bucle-for

buenas tardes, tengo la siguiente función en la cúal es una serie de errores que se generarán si algún atributo del objeto falta, estoy buscando la manera de poder simplificarlo con el uso de un ciclo for, pero no logro solucionarlo.

```
def validar_pareja_poderdante(self):
    poderdante = self.poderdantes[0]
    if self.cantidad_poderdantes == 1 and self.estado_civil_es_union(poderdante.estado_civil):
        if self.declaraciones.pareja_hace_parte_de_compraventa == 'Si' or self.declaraciones.pareja_hace_parte_de_compraventa == 'No': 
            
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.nombre:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "nombre".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.tipo_identificacion:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "tipo de identificación".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.numero_identificacion:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "número de identificación".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.ciudad_expedicion_identificacion:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "ciudad de expedición de identificación".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.domicilio_pais:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "domicilio país".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.domicilio_municipio:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "domicilio municipio".')
            if not self.pareja_poderdante.domicilio_departamento:
                raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "domicilio departamento".')
```

**Al correr la función, genera el error correctamente.**

```
raise ValidationError('Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "nombre".')
utils.exceptions.ValidationError: Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "nombre".
```

**La manera en la que intento implementar el ciclo for es la siguiente:**

```
def validar_pareja_poderdante(self):
     obligatorios = ['nombre', 'tipo_identificacion', 'numero_identificacion', 
                     'ciudad_expedicion_identificacion', 
                     'domicilio_pais','domicilio_municipio', 'domicilio_departamento', 
                     'genero']
     for obligatorio in obligatorios:
     valor = getattr(self, obligatorio)
         if not valor:
         raise ValidationError(f'Dato faltante de pareja poderdante: {obligatorio}')
```

**Al intentar correr la función con el ciclo for me genera el siguiente error:**

```
File "C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Escritorio\poderes\models\poder.py", line 107, in validar_pareja_poderdante
    valor = getattr(self, obligatorio)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DocumentoPoder' object has no attribute 'nombre'
```

Gracias por la atención prestada, espero alguien pudiera orientarme, cabe mencionar que no soy muy bueno en el ciclo for.

Comment: Casi lo logras! Solo tenés que obtener el atributo del objeto correcto en el getattr (es decir `getattr(self.pareja_poderdante, ...)`. En tu código original, tratas de obtener el valor a validar de una instancia de DocumentoPoder.

Comment: yo usaría el manejo de excepciones de python

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. era ese pequeño detalle.

Comment: Juan, ¡aceptaste una _no-respuesta_! Si lo que dijo @DanteS. fue lo que te ha sido útil, o le pides que redacte una respuesta (para aceptarla), o redactas por tu cuenta una respuesta mencionando lo que él te comentó. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
class ClassName():

    errors={
        "siExisto" : "estoy definido weee!!!",
        "nombre" : 'Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "nombre".',
        "tipo_identificacion" :'Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "tipo de identificación".',
        "numero_identificacion" : 'Dato faltante de pareja de poderdante "número de identificación".'
        
    }

    def __init__(self, arg):
            self.nombre=None
            self.tipo_identificacion=None
            self.numero_identificacion=None
            self.siExisto="hola"

    def test(self):
        print(self.__dict__.keys())

        for x in self.errors:
            if not getattr(self, x):
                raise ValidationError("{}".format(self.errors[x]))

        


example = ClassName(1)
example.test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si ves en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) de `getattr()`, la función puede recibir un tercer parámetro: el valor default. Puedes hacer uso de esto de la siguiente forma:

```py
def validar_pareja_poderdante(self):
    obligatorios = ['nombre', 'tipo_identificacion', 'numero_identificacion', 
                     'ciudad_expedicion_identificacion', 
                     'domicilio_pais','domicilio_municipio', 'domicilio_departamento', 
                     'genero']
    for obligatorio in obligatorios:
        valor = getattr(self, obligatorio, None)  # Por default será None
        if not valor:
            raise ValidationError(f'Dato faltante de pareja poderdante: {obligatorio}')
```

La condición que tienes ya está preparada para tirar la excepción si `valor` es `None`!